# Can't import my own PyPI package

Tags: python, pypi

I am trying to make a package available on PyPI. I have uploaded it to PyPI, and it can be installed as follows:
`pip install autostager`. However, opening up the shell and trying to import it does not work as expected:

```
>>> import autostager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named autostager
```

For reference, here is `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
  name = 'autostager',
  packages = ['autostager'],
  version = '0.1',
  description = 'Stage a directory based on Github pull request (e.g., dynamic puppet environments)',
  author = 'Jordan Facibene',
  author_email = 'jordan.facibene13@stjohns.edu',
  url = 'https://github.com/jfach/autostager',
  download_url = 'https://github.com/jfach/autostager/tarball/0.1',
  keywords = ['github', 'automation', 'staging'],
  classifiers = []
)
```

For reference, my repository can be found here: https://github.com/jfach/autostager

The module that I would want to import would be `autostager.py` (among others) found in the `autostager` directory.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `autostager` doesn't appear to have an `__init__.py` and therefore isn't itself a module. Does importing from it like that work locally when you `python setup.py develop` or `... install`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe should `__init__.py` go in the root directory or the `autostager` subdirectory?

Comment: In the *module* root, at the same level as your `autostager.py` file.

Comment: You should answer the question with that! That got me up and running.