# IDE does not recognise my own package from pypi

Tags: python, fastapi, pypi, uvicorn

I am attempting to use my own package that I have uploaded to Pypi, similar to this user done in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662095/cant-import-my-own-pypi-package) but adding the init file at my root folder does not seem to work.

For ref this is my package [link](https://pypi.org/project/heart-disease-classification-model/) with my package called heart-disease-classification-model.
[This](https://github.com/ChngYuanLongRandy/demo_deploy) is the github repo

I have installed the package with the correct version using pip in my virtualenv but when I run the command:`uvicorn api:app --reload`

The error points to this line:
`from heart-disease-classification-model.predict import make_prediction_inputs_api`
which leads me to suspect that the build is not done properly.

My api file:

```
import pandas as pd
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from config.settings import API_VERSION, APP_NAME
from heart-disease-classification-model import make_prediction_inputs_api
import schema
from config.settings import API_VERSION

# I initialise these as static first
MODEL_NAME = 'Random Forest'
MODEL_VERSION = '0.0.2'

app = FastAPI()

# root, display a rudimentary homepage
@app.get('/')
def homepage():
    return {'message':f'Welcome to {APP_NAME}'}

@app.get("/health", response_model=schema.health, status_code=200)
def health_of_api():

    health =schema.health(apiVerson =API_VERSION, modelVersion= MODEL_VERSION,modelName= MODEL_NAME )

    return health.dict()

@app.post('/predict', response_model=schema.PredictionResults, status_code=200)
async def predict_value(input_data):
    input_df = pd.DataFrame(jsonable_encoder(input_data.inputs))

    results = make_prediction_inputs_api(input_data=input_df)

    if results['errors'] is not None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail= json.loads(results["errors"]))

    return results
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Dashes aren't allowed in package names anyway; `heart-disease-classification-model` must be something like `heart_disease_classification_model`.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the issue was due to how I named the root folder. In this case my root folder was named 'src' instead of my package name so I had to simply import src, beginner's mistake.

Comment: That's not a good idea at all. What if you'd have multiple packages of your own with the `src` layout?

Comment: yep. Will avoid that in the future for sure